# Host my service in IIS or windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a couple of services, where one of them needs to be a singleton service. The other services connect to this singleton service and the singleton service in turn makes calls back in to the instances of the other services.

My question: is it safe to move this scenario into IIS so I can make use of the new Windows Server Appfabric features? I'm not sure how IIS handles instance management.

Comment: PS: The other services all keep a session alive with their client so that during this session the singleton service can propagate updates through these services to their clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS should not be problem in your scenario. If it already works with self hosting it should also work in IIS. You only need to be aware of some IIS management settings which control AppPool recycling etc.

Comment: IIS appears to be some kind of problem after all but I've already started a new question for that issue ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686776/multiple-net-tcp-endpoints-with-different-portnumbers-on-the-same-web-site-iis7

Answer (score 2):

I would go for IIS as well because compared to other hosting mechanisms you get a lot features for free:

- process life-cycle management,
- process recycling,
- shared hosting,
- on-demand activation,
- health monitoring

Answer (score 1):

Hosting in IIS is the way forward definitely. Especially if you have AppFabric installed as you mentioned.