# Multiple net.tcp endpoints with different portnumbers on the same web site (IIS7)

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have multiple services that have to run under one website. Two of the services have a net.tcp endpoint. The addresses are formatted as follows:

net.tcp://backend.ourcompany.com:9080/Product1/2010/09/Service1/Service1.svc

net.tcp://backend.ourcompany.com:9081/Product1/2010/09/Service2/Service2.svc

net.tcp://backend.ourcompany.com:9090/Product2/2010/09/Service2/Service2.svc

All services have their own Web.config. Currently all services have a different base address in their Web.config and a relative endpoint address. Everything worked ok with just the fist service installed, after installing the second I keep getting this error: 'This collection already contains an address with scheme net.tcp.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. If your service is being hosted in IIS you can fix the problem by setting 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/multipleSiteBindingsEnabled' to true or specifying 'system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/baseAddressPrefixFilters'.'

Since the multipleSiteBindingsEnabled is only for http (why?) I tried getting it to work with the baseAddressPrefixFilters but I don't really understand how that would help me in my case. Is it possible what I'm trying to do here? Otherwise this would be a big fail of IIS, in a self-hosted environment I'm doing the same thing for years. I now want to migrate my existing services to IIS because of the AppFabric monitoring features.

Comment: So for clarity, the error starts showing up after I edit my site bindings in IIS and add a second net.tcp binding with another port.

Comment: So you have single site and multiple applications in this site. Each application expects different port for net.tcp services? What about creation of separate sites for each application?

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment as a workaround. I think IIS sees a web site as some kind of an atomic thing and therefore I can't add multiple bindings of the same type.